# Youtube API V3 I Can't Count My Subscriber

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, subscription, youtube-data-api

I need to count my subscriptions on Java but I can't fix, please help me!

I use this Code:

```
HttpRequestInitializer httpRequestInitializer = new HttpRequestInitializer() {
    public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
    }
};

YouTube youTube = new YouTube.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), httpRequestInitializer)
        .setApplicationName("<Your-Application-Name>")
        .build();
YouTube.Channels.List search = youTube.channels().list("statistics");
search.setForUsername("codeherenow");
search.setKey("<Insert-API-Key>");
ChannelListResponse response = search.execute();

List<Channel> channels = response.getItems();
for (Channel channel : channels) {
    System.out.println(channel.getStatistics().getSubscriberCount());
}
```

Comment: What do you mean you can't? What is it that you can't do exactly?

Comment: I mean i can't fix this code

Answer (score 0):

The new update in Youtube API is that you can't use [Channels: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) to count subscribers anymore.

`mySubscribers` (boolean)

> This parameter has been deprecated. This parameter can only be used in
>   a properly authorized request. Use the
>   [subscriptions.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list)
>   method and its mySubscribers parameter to retrieve a list of
>   subscribers to the authenticated user's channel.

Try to make a [REST call in Java](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) using this URI request:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&mySubscribers=true&fields=pageInfo&key={SERVER_API_KEY}
```

The totalResults key holds the number of subscribers, an example of response:

```
{
   "pageInfo": {
   "totalResults": 2,
   "resultsPerPage": 5
  }
}
```

Here, totalResults is the number of subscribers.

Comment: Thank You but Have A Little Problem Im Beginner For Java I don't Know how do that. Can you Help Me?

Comment: I don't do much Android either. I suggest you learn the ins-and-outs of your tool :)

Comment: Thank you for answer. But i don't have too much time for learn can you teach me please? I really need this code please.